# Getting error while displaying Indian currency symbol with Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am getting error "Invalid currency code: ₹" while adding currency symbol to price with Angular2. I have gone through some of the blogs, most of them suggest html entity should work but it didn't.

My code looks like:

```
{{ product.price | currency: '&#8377;'}}
```

I have also tried:

```
{{ product.price | currency: '&#8377;': true}}
```

The code works fine if I try with currency USD. What would be the proper syntax of doing it for getting the Rupee symbol?

Comment: Try using the currency ISO Code in your case it should bei: INR

Comment: Thanks cyrix! It worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can get Indian Rupee symbol with 'INR'. The code should be like:

```
{{ product.price | currency: 'INR': true}}
```